# prove that if two numbers are relatively prime, then number of their divisors multiplied equals the number of divisors of their product

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was asked to prove that for any two positive integers $a, b$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, $\tau(ab) = 
\tau(a)\tau(b)$. where $\tau(n)$ is deﬁned to be the number of divisors of $n$, including $1$ and $n$.

But, I did not know how to approach this can anyone please help me?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839984/prove-that-sigma-k-is-a-multiplicative-function) is another duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$. After you have this information, use the [formula for finding the number of factors for a number](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/NumberOfFactors.shtml) and you're done.